# Four tables in relation, PatientDetails, Symptoms, Medicine and Follow up

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists PatientDetails
( pt_id varchar(15) not null,
  pt_name varchar(20) not null,
  pt_sname varchar(20) not null,
  pt_age numeric,
  primary key(pt_id));

create table if not exists who_staging.Symptom (
sypt_id varchar(12) not null,
symptom varchar(20) not null,
primary key(sypt_id)
);

create table if not exists Medicine(
medi_id varchar(12) not null,
medi_name varchar(20) not null,
sypt_id varchar(12),
foreign key(sypt_id) references who_staging.symptom(sypt_id),
primary key(medi_id)
);

create table if not exists who_staging.FollowUp(
F_id varchar(10) not null,
pt_id varchar(15),
sypt_id varchar(12),
medi_id varchar(12),
foreign key(pt_id) references who_staging.PatientDetails(pt_id),
foreign key(sypt_id) references who_staging.symptom(sypt_id),
foreign key(medi_id) references who_staging.Medicine(medi_id),
primary key(F_id)
);
```

Is this referencing correct for the following?

1. One patient can have multiple symptoms.
2. For One symptom multiple medicines can be given.
3. For multiple symptoms, one medicine can be given.
4. One patient can have multiple Followup.
5. When particular Follow up no is selected, the system should show that   patient details as well as what medicine patient is taking for which symptom he/she is suffering from.

I would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: for starters pt_id isn't so hot. Why not shoot for an auto_inc int id ? Who is assigning that patient id anyway and with an auto_inc you don't have to dream one up

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that pt_id comes from some other system otherwise @drew comment is a better choice. The follow up table **should** have auto increment int id because your system creates them and it's better to automatically create the unique keys.

1 is correct because 4 is correct - Your schema allows multiple follow-up per patient and each follow-up is for one symptom and one medicine for that symptom for that patient.

2 is correct because there can be multiple medicine rows with the same symptom

3 is correct because there can be multiple medicine rows with different symptoms

5 will work and so will selecting a patient ID and displaying all of the follow ups for that patient.

So, overall, this is a good start but consider the suggestions for keys. You will probably find some ways to improve as you go.